# All function calls are null?

Tags: null, func, godot, gdscript

For some reason every time I go to call a function it is null, no matter the circumstances. It could be .set(), .set_text(), or even .connect()
I can't tell if this is the engine issue or what (I'm using the latest build...), but I can't seem to find this issue anywhere else. I don't know what to do to fix it.

Comment: It is best if you can post your codes here for us to check and help.

Comment: if func doesnt return anything - its return null

Comment: What do you mean "it is null"?  It returns null?  It says you're trying to call the function on a null object?